# Indexes Stuck on "processing"

Tags: indexing, ee-1.13

Both the Product URL Rewrites index and Category/Product association have been running for days according to the Magento Admin
[image: stuck!]

However, there are no reindex php processes running, the `var/locks` folder is empty, and the `index_process` MySQL table has completely different statuses:

```
+------------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| process_id | indexer_code                 | status          | started_at          | ended_at            | mode   |
+------------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
|          1 | catalog_product_attribute    | pending         | 2014-01-03 18:17:32 | 2014-01-03 18:17:34 | manual |
|          2 | catalog_product_price        | pending         | 2013-11-06 21:26:32 | 2013-11-06 21:26:32 | manual |
|          3 | catalog_url                  | pending         | 2013-06-05 22:15:24 | 2013-06-05 22:15:24 | manual |
|          4 | catalog_product_flat         | require_reindex | 2013-06-05 22:15:24 | 2013-06-05 22:15:24 | manual |
|          5 | catalog_category_flat        | require_reindex | 2013-08-13 19:55:56 | 2013-08-13 19:55:56 | manual |
|          6 | catalog_category_product     | pending         | 2013-06-05 22:15:24 | 2013-06-05 22:15:24 | manual |
|          7 | catalogsearch_fulltext       | require_reindex | 2014-01-03 15:05:55 | 2013-12-16 22:33:51 | manual |
|          8 | cataloginventory_stock       | pending         | 2014-01-03 18:17:32 | 2014-01-03 18:17:32 | manual |
|          9 | tag_summary                  | pending         | 2014-01-03 15:51:59 | 2014-01-03 15:52:02 | manual |
|         10 | url_redirect                 | pending         | 2013-06-05 22:17:14 | 2013-06-05 22:17:14 | manual |
|         11 | targetrule                   | require_reindex | 2013-07-03 16:37:34 | 2013-07-03 16:37:34 | manual |
|         12 | catalog_url_category         | pending         | 2013-06-05 22:17:15 | 2013-06-05 22:17:15 | manual |
|         13 | catalog_url_product          | pending         | 2013-06-05 22:17:15 | 2013-06-05 22:17:15 | manual |
|         14 | catalog_category_product_cat | pending         | 2013-06-05 22:17:15 | 2013-06-05 22:17:15 | manual |
+------------+------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

What could be causing this discrepancy? More worrisome, it's keeping us from completing the upgrade to 1.13.1 (don't worry, this is just the staging server!)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A server timeout might causing Magento Admin Reindexing to stuck on "Processing" forever. What you need to do is to get SSH access for your server and depending on which reindex you got stuck, preform the following command lines.

```
php yourmagentofolder/html/shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_attribute
php yourmagentofolder/html/shell/indexer.php -reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php yourmagentofolder/html/shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_category_flat
php yourmagentofolder/html/shell/indexer.php -reindex cataloginventory_stock
php yourmagentofolder/html/shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_category_product
php yourmagentofolder/html/shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_price
php yourmagentofolder/html/shell/indexer.php -reindex tag_summary
php yourmagentofolder/html/shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_url
```

Comment: The issue occurs when reindexing using `indexer.php`

Comment: Did you try to increase the Maximum Execution Time within the php configuration?

Comment: I believe PHP's CLI ini file always defines `max_execution_time` to be zero. Anyway, it looks like your recommendation to run them individually is working. The issue was occuring when calling `php indexer.php reindexall`. Thanks!

Comment: Then you are probably running into a memory error.

Comment: Deleting the var/locks folder first allowed me to run these processes

Comment: Use ```php indexer.php info``` to get the complete list of indexes.

Comment: i face the same issue, when i run the above in command line the re-index process as good, if i run the php indexer.php info i got the following error "Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Indexer model is not defined.'"

Answer (score 2):

I was upgrading to v1.9CE from v1.3CE. The Category Products would not reindex. I had to drop the catalog_category_product_index table from the v1.9 DB and replace it with the table from the LIVE site.

1. Export the table (catalog_category_product_index) from the latest (in this case, active) database. You must checkmark “Disable foreign key checks”.
2. Select the database that you will import this table to.
3. Click the SQL tab.
4. Enter this code: DROP TABLE catalog_category_product_index
5. Then import the backed up table
6. Reindex in SSH: -reindex catalog_category_product
7. Check Magento admin. Index management shows no errors.